# Choices work flow

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to have choices in Cognito Forms be able to dictate what page to go to.  In example:

1. choice 1
2. choice 2

If I pick `choice 1` I would like to be directed to page 3 of my form.  If I pick `choice 2` I would like to be directed to page 4 in my form and so on.  I have tried the editor with =(choice.contains("choice")) but it just keeps sending me to a blank page and not jumping pages.

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) allows you to specify when to show a page using robust conditional logic options.  This differs from the "jump to" page approach, but provides similar capabilities while providing better/more consistent support for navigating back to previous pages.

In this case, for the Page Break before page three, you would want to select Show Next Page - When, and specify to show page three when =Choice = "Choice 1".  This will then look like the following:

[image]

[image]

You can then do the same for the page break above page four, setting the next page to be visible when "Choice 2" is selected.